# Doctrine 2 Classloader weird behaviour - wrong paths to classes

Tags: php, orm, classloader, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm having a bit of a problem with Classloader added to Doctrine 2 project.
I have simple directory structure like this:

- config (bootstrap file)
- html (docroot with templates/images/js etc)
- php
- Entities (doctrine 2 entities)
- Responses (some transport objects)
- Services (processing api and business logic - like session beans in java)

Each of the php subdirectories belongs to its own namespace (same as the name of directory).
I want to use aforementioned classloader to load these three different packages, so my bootstrap looks like this:

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', $lib );
$classLoader->register();

$responsesCL = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Responses', __DIR__.'/../php');
$responsesCL->register();

$entitiesCL = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__.'/../php');
$entitiesCL->register();

$servicesCL = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Services', __DIR__.'/../php');
$servicesCL->register();
```

Bold DIR is actually `__ DIR __` php constant.

Now, I am referring in my services package to entities and this is where the problem starts, for some reason I get errors due to file not found problem, for example:

> Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/projects/PlatformManagement/config/../php/Services/Entities/User.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in
>   **/usr/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php**
>   on line **148**

Somehow, there is extra 'Services' in the path, and obviously it's not valid path. I am a bit puzzled why that extra directory there? I tripple checked all namespaces, calls, and they are ok.

I need another pair of eyes to have look, I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious here, but can't spot it :|

Oh, this is latest Doctrine 2 Beta (4) and php 5.3.3 on fedora if that's of any help.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: The problem was when I tried to use classes from packages. I was using Entities\ClassName.class rather than \Entities\ClassName.class

Answer (score 0):

Is there any something like Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR()?

Doctrine's Autoloader may produce unexpected behaviors because it loads classes based on PHP include paths.

refer to [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/class-loading.html#usage)

In your case, Entities should have

```
namespace Entities;
```

declaration, not anything else.

And use entities like below,

```
use Entities\User;
new User;
```